# Half circle shape with flat bottom border

Tags: html, css

I want to create a shape like this

*Behind the number circle*

[image]

I have already started something but cannot organize my border from bottom

```css
.circle {
  background: yellow;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.shape {
  background: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 10px solid #000;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape">
  <div class="circle">

  </div>
</div>
```

Or a link to a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4fq95bcj/5/

its a half-circle with `bottom-left` and `bottom-right` border longer ..

Comment: The best way is use SVG.

Comment: updated the duplicate to a better one